# SSIS - Add package variable to existing collection

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package in which I am returning the results of a query into a collection. 
My query is returning 8 columns. For example:

```
     first name
     last name
     employee
     id
     city
     state
     zip
     hire-date
```

I am iterating through each item in the collection and do some manipulation in a For-each loop container.

I need to pass in a 9th element to the collection which is a package variable.

```
 Example: Active_Flag
```

How would I go about that?
   One approach I am thinking is to read the collection into an array in a script task and add the 9th element to it.

I tried this, but the collection couldn't read it and I keep getting a

"Error: The enumerator failed to retrieve element at index "9".

Any ideas how I could go about this?

Comment: It's entirely likely that you can do what you need in SQL. Can you explain what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: Concur with sentiments of Nick & Ferdipux. You have everything there already - the data set + the parameter value. If you just need a Variable that holds the value from the Parameter - that's silly but trivial. Create your variable with the same type as the parameter and use an Expression to assign the value to the Variable as the Parameter. Assuming we're not dealing with parameters marked as Sensitive.

Comment: Otherwise, yes, you're going to need to pass the Object into a Script Task as a read/write variable and then create a new collection with 9 elements and pour the old into the new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches to your problem:

- Think twice - do you really need 9th row? You are iterating with a *For-Each* loop over an Object variable, extracting 8 rows into package variables and doing something. Adding 9th package variable to Loop logic and existing 8 variables seems easier then repackaging Object variable with OLEDB collection.
- If adding 9th column makes more sense to you, you can do it in SQL query. Create package variable type String with `EvaluateAsExpression=true` and `Expression` property like
  `="Select ..., '"+(DT_WSTR, 10)@[User::YourVariable]+"' AS [ninethcol] from ..."`
  This sample adds string data, you can modify it to return desired data type.
  Then set SQL Task where you extract your data with SQL Source from variable. This will inject 9th column with flexible content to the query.

Comment: I guess  - that is where I am stuck, adding the 9th variable to the For-Each logic. I added the variable in the package and tried to bring it in the variable mappings in For-Each loop, but it threw the enumerator error as well. So, was thinking i should go the adding to collection route.

Comment: Thank you. Adding it to the query as a variable and then reading into the collection  worked.